# Calculating difference between two date picker fields in number of days in infopath

Tags: infopath, date-time, infopath-rules, datepicker

I am trying to calculate the difference between two date picker fields which should result the value in number of days in infopath.

I tried number(substring(field1, 9, 2)) - number(substring(field2, 9, 2)) but it calculates on the different in dates and does not consider month. If the field one is 5th May 2020 and field 2 is 6th Jun 2020, it still gives the difference as 1.

Can anyone help by suggesting how can this be achieved?

Thank you.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23234/103219.aspx) if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, Ganesh. It helped! :)

Comment: Great, I am glad it helped you. I am writing it as an answer below. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to your problem :

1. Using qrules(not free)
2. Use rules, conditions, and the **number()**, **floor()**, and **substring()** functions in formulas to calculate the difference between two date picker controls in InfoPath.

You can read more about it in below question on forum:

[Help please-Solve: Number of days = (todays date - date initiated)](https://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23234/103219.aspx)